# Delete all lines in a text file that do not contain a string

Tags: shell, sed

So I've got a txt file where each line is a file path, I would like to:

1. Read this txt file (line-by-line).
2. Delete all lines that do not end with `,-,.txt`
3. In the remaining lines, delete everything from after the last `/` to the `,-,.txt`.
4. Write the output to a new txt.

How could this be done with sed?

Input:

```
/a/b1/
/a/b1/car
/a/b1/car/bil/
/a/b1/car/bil/,-,.txt
/a/b2/
/a/b2/flower
/a/b2/flower/bil/
/a/b2/flower/bil/,-,.txt
/a/b2/
/a/b2/boat
/a/b2/boat/baat/
/a/b2/boat/baat/abc,-,.txt
```

Second step:

```
/a/b1/car/bil/,-,.txt
/a/b2/flower/bil/,-,.txt
/a/b2/boat/baat/abc,-,.txt
```

Third step/desired output:

```
/a/b1/car/bil/
/a/b2/flower/bil/
/a/b2/boat/baat/
```

Comment: A short sample source for testing would be fine. Else, everyone has to produce his own.

Comment: `sed` is a stream editor.  It doesn't read an entire file into memory; it (usually) reads and processes a line at a time.  Which should be exactly what you need for your requirements (ignoring #1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -n '/,-,\.txt$/s|/[^/]*$||p' input.txt > output.txt
```

What it does:

It reads a line at a time from `input.txt`; `-n` tells it not to print lines by default.  For each line that matches the pattern `,-,\.txt$`, everything consisting of a `/` character followed by zero or more non-`/` characters, up to the end of the line, is deleted (i.e., from the *last* `/` to the end of the line); I use `|` as the delimiter so I don't have to escape the `/`.

This is a fairly straightforward rendition of your requirements.

Now that you've posted sample input and output, I see that you want to keep the final `/` (which is inconsistent with your requirement "delete everything from the last `/` to the `,-,.txt`").  To do that:

```
sed -n '/,-,\.txt$/s|/[^/]*$|/|p' input.txt > output.txt
```

This produces your expected results given your sample input.

If I were doing this on the fly, I might use a simpler approach, combining `sed` and `grep`:

```
grep ',-,\.txt$' input.txt | sed 's|/[^/]*$|/|' > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be sed? i would use python for such thing, sed is quickly over complicated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

def main(fin, fout):
    with open(fin) as f:
        lines = []
        for line in f.readlines():
            if line.endswith(',-,.txt\n'):
                lines.append('/'.join(line.split('/')[:-1]) + '/\n')

    with open(fout, 'w') as f:
        for line in lines:
            f.write(line)

def usage():
    print sys.argv[0], "filename new_file"
    print 'remove all lines not ending with ",-,.txt"'
    print 'print the resulting lines, up to their last "/" to new file'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        main(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
    else:
        usage()
```

tested with sample

```
/a/b1/car/bil/
/a/b2/flower/bil/
/a/b2/boat/baat/
```

Comment: no, python would be just fine, (the question has been updated)

Comment: updated, it should work for your use case, there has been simple sed answers since though

Comment: Keith's sed solution is 24 characters long.  Do you really think that is "overly complicated"?  The python solution seems a lot more complex.

Comment: Well, producing Keith's solution require good sed knowledges and understanding it needed explanations (that he nicely gave), i agree it's a nice solution, but it's really harder to understand, and to produce, i love sed, mind you, but it's a bit of a dark art to me. Of course, using python for this require a good bit of boilerplate code for such a task (the core of the solution is 3 lines long) but imho, it's clearer.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo -e "foo,-,.txt\nbar,-,.png" | sed -rn '/,-,\.txt/{s/^(.*),-,\.txt$/\1/p}'
```

explanation:

```
sed -rn : 
    -r  : use regular expressions, which allows (.*) as  
          capturing group without masking the parens. 
    -n  : no output by default 
    '/pattern/{ list of commands}' 
    {s/pattern/replacement/p} substitute pattern with replacement,  
       then print. 
    /^(.*)foo$/ : from line begin ^ to line end $, with anything 
       before foo being captured, to be outputted with \1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep -oP '.*/(?=[^/]*,-,\.txt$)' input.txt
/a/b1/car/bil/
/a/b2/flower/bil/
/a/b2/boat/baat/
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
sed -r '/,-,\.txt$/!d' <file> | awk -F, '{print $1}'
```

Notes:

- The `sed` command removes the lines that don't match the pattern (`!d`)
- The `awk` command prints just the first field in a line with multiple fields separated by commas. This seems to be what you're looking for according to the input and desired output provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

in your question you showed us two steps, is it acceptable if it is done in one short by a sed onliner?

```
sed -r  '/,-,\.txt/!d; s#/[^/]*$#/#' yourFile
```

works with your example data.

see the test below:

```
kent$  cat t.txt
/a/b1/
/a/b1/car
/a/b1/car/bil/
/a/b1/car/bil/,-,.txt
/a/b2/
/a/b2/flower
/a/b2/flower/bil/
/a/b2/flower/bil/,-,.txt
/a/b2/
/a/b2/boat
/a/b2/boat/baat/
/a/b2/boat/baat/abc,-,.txt

kent$  sed -r  '/,-,\.txt/!d; s#/[^/]*$#/#' t.txt
/a/b1/car/bil/
/a/b2/flower/bil/
/a/b2/boat/baat/
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/[^/]*,-,\.txt$//p;d' file
```